# Is there anyone Strickland doesn't think is a slacker?

Tags: back-to-the-future

Throughout the *Back to the Future* series, we see that Strickland, sorry, *Mr* Strickland calls Marty a 'slacker' and George a slacker, even the guys shooting at his house are slackers.  **Do we know of anyone who Mr Strickland *doesn't* think as being a slacker?**  Non-canon answers will be accepted.  I would be especially interested to see whether this is mentioned at all in the television series.

Comment: It appears to either be genetic or heavily pressed upon offspring (e.g., Marshal Strickland in Part III). So Principal Strickland's father, and if he had a son, would be a safe bets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only person I can recall whom Strickland mentions, but doesn't call a slacker, is Doc Brown.  Strickland labels Doc a "dangerous... nutcase", but not a slacker.

> STRICKLAND:
>   Let me give you a nickel's worth of free advice, young man.  This so-called Dr. Brown is dangerous. He's a real nutcase.

But the [Back to the Future wiki](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Slacker) seems to suggest that the actual number of people deemed by Strickland to be "slackers" is relatively small:

[image]

Comment: I would add that his father and/or son if he has one he does not consider a slacker. Also himself.